# How to overlay multiple graphs from Apple Health data

Tags: ios, health.app, health-kit

With Apple Health in iOS 9, how can I see the interaction between multiple data categories? For example, if I enter data for menstruation and sexual activity, it would be nice to see a graph with both of those overlaid on one another.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're describing doesn't exist in the Health app. However, it's possible there's some App Store app that reads such data from HealthKit and can display a combined chart.